# PHP Mailer You must provide at least one email address

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

function smtpmailer($to,$from,$subject,$body) { 
    define('GUSER', 'xxx'); // Gmail username
    define('GPWD', 'xxx'); // Gmail password
    printf("list:".$to);
    $recipient = array ($to);
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, "Bank Negara");
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    foreach ($recipient as $email){
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    }
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am passing a string which hold the email address in such format:

```
'email1@yahoo.com','email2@gmail.com'
```

When I am passing this

```
$recipient = array ($to);
```

I am having error Invalid address: But When I pass the string output directly like this:

```
$recipient = array ('email1@yahoo.com','email2@gmail.com');
```

It works fine. How should pass my $to String to this $recipient array.

Comment: I've removed your gmail account/password information from this post. You should probably change that password right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$addresses = "'email1@yahoo.com','email2@gmail.com'";
$to = array($addresses);
```

is not going to magically create an array with two elements in it. What you'll get is a SINGLE element in the array, e.g

```
$to = array(
    0 => "'email1@yahoo.com','email2@gmail.com'"
);
```

However, doing

```
$to = explode(',', $addresses);
```

WILL give you a two element array:

```
$to = array (
    0 => "...yahoo",
    1 => "...gmail"
);
```

Comment: Do you need to trim the single quotes from each element? My guess is that an address of `"'email1@yahoo.com'"` will not be valid because of the single quotes as part of the string.