# PHPMailer: You must provide at least one recipient email address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) on my website, but it returns an error:

**You must provide at least one recipient email address.**

The server is running PHP 7. I've checked out the following pages looking for answers:

- [PHP Mailer You must provide at least one email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297367/php-mailer-you-must-provide-at-least-one-email-address)
- [PHP Mailer Error: Mailer Error - must provide at least one recipient email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188954/php-mailer-error-mailer-error-must-provide-at-least-one-recipient-email-addre)
- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/441
- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/429

None of those solved my problem.

This is the way it's set up:

```
require_once 'lib/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$m = new PHPMailer;

$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;
$m->SMTPDebug = 2;

$m->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com';
$m->Username = 'email@email.com';
$m->Password = 'password';
$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$m->Port = 465;

$m->From = 'email@email.com';
$m->FromName = 'Name';

$m->Subject = 'Testing PHPMailer';
$m->Body = 'Body of the email. Testing PHPMailer.';

if (!$m->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $m->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Everything OK.';
}
```

Doing `var_dump(PHPMailer::validateAddress('email@email.com'));` returns `true`. So the email address doesn't seem to be the issue.

**EDIT**

Adding `$m->AddAddress = email@email.com` doesn't solve the issue. It returns the exact same error.

**EDIT 2**

Have added $m->addAddress('email@email.com') to the code. I had been doing that wrong. It now returns a 500 error.

**EDIT 3**

Turns out I mistyped the addAddress in my code (I misplaced a quote, which caused the 500 error). The provided answer stands. I did not properly add a recipient.

My apologies for troubling you with this. I should've more carefully looked at the PHPMailer example provided, instead of blindly following a third part tutorial.

Comment: I don't see you setting a recipient anywhere. The recipient is whose receiving the message, not whose sending it.

Comment: add your complete code

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sorry, should've mentioned in the question, adding  a recipient doesn't change the result. Still the same error.

Comment: That's... not how you add a recipient.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam This is the complete code. It's just for testing purposes. Once the page is loaded, it's supposed to send an email.

Comment: @idix so where `$m->addAddress` ?? in your Code !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't added a recipient address. You need to do this:

```
$m->addAddress('email@email.com');
```

Take a look at PHPMailer's example:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Sorry, I should have mentioned in my question. I already tried that. Still returns the exact same error. Updating question.

Comment: Your updated code `$m->AddAddress = email@email.com` is not correct! Look closely again at what I showed you.

Comment: @idix `addAddress` is a method, not a field.